# How can I get the string between repeated DYNAMIC html tags in a string using javascript? (No regex unless its the only way!)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, substring

As a mean to explain I am not posting the gigantic string I have (which contains dynamic html tags and are auto-generated with unique id). I want to get the text between every tag that says `"<p class=partial_entry>... comment...</p>"` **using anything excep Regex**, and in my case ill have a string of 20 repeated tags by getting the outerHTML. I have an example below:

```
var str = "<div class=prw_rup prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-name=reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-init=handlers>
<div class=entry><p class=partial_entry>You have to try their special sushi rolls like acevichado or patrullero. They have great selections of sushi and other dishes.</p>
</div></div><div class=prw_rup prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-name=reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-init=handlers><div class=entry><p class=partial_entry>
All you can eat sushi fir $20 ($24 including tax)! Christian, our server, was wonderful and attentive.
</p></div></div><div class=prw_rup prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-name=reviews_text_summary_hsx data-prwidget-init=handlers>
<div class=entry><p class=partial_entry>The place was good, also the waiters, but definitely sushi is the best in town 
for my opinion, even with the few options of it in this place. I will be there soon again.</p></div></div>";
```

What I want is the 3 comments I have in my example so I use the code for 20:

```
- You have to try their special sushi rolls like acevichado or patrullero. They have great selections of sushi and other dishes.

- All you can eat sushi fir $20 ($24 including tax)! Christian, our server, was wonderful and attentive.

- The place was good, also the waiters, but definitely sushi is the best in town for my opinion, even with the few options of it in this place. I will be there soon again.
```

I tried making my own code but the text or tags in between are not taken off since it detects the tag I preset, example: `"THE WHOLE STRING AFTER THE TAG IM LOOKING FOR + <p class=partial_entry>... comment...</p>"` and I only want `...comment...` part.

The code I made is below:

```
var temp = "<p class=partial_entry";
    var res = str.split('>');
    var res2 = res.indexOf(temp) + 1;
    var resultado = null;
    
     if (res2 < res.length && res2 != -1) {
         resultado = res[ res2 ]; // gets the next one
    }
    
    alert(resultado);
```

Comment: Why would you get the outerHTML then extract the texts from it? Why not extract the texts directly from the DOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). For the record, I did read that you don't want to use regex, but the answer is the same in either instance; use an [x]html parser.  You have access to the DOM, so why not use it?

Comment: Because I have dynamic tags and they auto-generated (and the only way possible), was by getting the whole container of the tags and filter out the comments. I cant get the innerText of it because I will get only 1 comment.

Comment: @EAlexisMT Sounds like a problem with your code, and not js; but it will be impossible to fix that code if you don't show us it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty trivial, assuming the comments will *always* be wrapped in a node with class `partial_entry`:

```
var commentNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('partial_entry');
var comments = [];
for (var i = 0; i < commentNodes.length; i++) {
  comments.push(commentNodes[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: I'll check this.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Does it really? I don't see it listed on MDN, and `HTMLCollection.prototype.map` doesn't seem to give any official results (if it really is official somewhere, I'm really curious)

Comment: @CertainPerformance as a _pollyfill_: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300

Comment: Oh, I see what was confusing me. "Polyfill" refers to something that implements a *standard* or a *proposed standard*. But `HTMLCollection.prototype.map` isn't either of those - `core-js` is *both* a polyfill (for newish features like `Array.prototype.flat`) *and* a library for useful but non-standard features (like having `HTMLCollection` inherit from `Array`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's a good distinction to make, thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop that loops through every single character until it sees , then stores every character until it sees

It probably isn't the best way, and won't work if there's other tags inside the p. But it works.

```js
var text = "<p class=partial_entry>This text should show up</p>"
var seenBeginTag = false;
var seenEndTag = false;
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
{
  if (seenBeginTag && seenEndTag) {
    if (text[i] == '<')
    {
      seenBeginTag = false;
      seenEndTag = false;
    }
    else {
      output.push(text[i]);
    }
  }
  else if (seenBeginTag) {
    if (text[i] == '>')
    {
      seenEndTag = true;
    }
  }
  else if (text[i] == '<') {
    if (text[i+1] == 'p') {
      seenBeginTag = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(output.join(''));
```